# Jquery change id, not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following code to change the id of a div to something else, but it's not working??? Does anyone know why?

the if statement gives back a true so the div with the id of 'id' does exist but it's not running the actual line that changes the id

```
function grav_treasure(){
var i=0;
for(i=0;i<=treasure_list.length;i++){
    var id = treasure_list[i];
    if($("#"+id).length > 0){
        var current_top = document.getElementById(id).style.top;
        var current_top = parseFloat(current_top);
        var id_split = id.split("_");
        var row = id_split[2];
        var row = parseFloat(row) + 1;
        var col = id_split[5];
        var col = parseFloat(col);
        var block_id = "row_" + row + "_col_" + col + "_type_grass";

        if($("#"+block_id).length > 0){
            if(document.getElementById(block_id).getAttribute('class')=="block"){

            }
            else{
                var rand_id=Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
                var new_id = "treasure_grass_"+row+"_"+rand_id;
                var new_id = new_id + "_col_" + col;
                treasure_list.push(new_id);
                if($("#"+id).length > 0){
                    alert(new_id);
                    $("#"+id).attr('id',new_id);
                    grav_treasure_tree(id, row);
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            var rand_id=Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
            var new_id = "treasure_grass_"+row+"_"+rand_id;
            var new_id = new_id + "_col_" + col;
            treasure_list.push(new_id);
            if($("#"+id).length > 0){
                alert(new_id);
                $("#"+id).attr('id',new_id);
                grav_treasure_tree(id, row);
            }
        }

    }
}
setTimeout("grav_treasure()",100)
}
```

**Sorry for anyone who tried to answer this, I made a small mistake by inputing a wrong variable into a function which screwed up everything, so there was actualy nothing wrong with the script above. Sorry :( but thanks for all your help!**

Comment: Does the condition of that if statement evaluate to true?

Comment: Why are you declaring new_id twice?

Comment: Do all the variables contain the expected values? Where does the `id` come from in `if($("#"+id).length > 0)` does *that* contain an expected value? The second time you declare the `var new_id` you over-write the first declaration. Did you mean `new_id += new_id + "_col_" + col;`?

Comment: Please provide a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo instead of a not even running piece of code. There are already missing bits here and we don't know if this is your actual problem or if just because you posted the snippet out of context (e.g. `row`, `col`, `id` and `grav_treasure_tree` are not defined). You should post a *self-contained* example. Of course we can apply common sense but it is much easier to help if we don't have to guess or assume.

Comment: Further to Felix's comment, may I suggest a read of [SSCCE (Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example)](http://www.sscce.org/)?

Comment: I've posted the whole function :) Maybe that helps. I'm declaring id twice because I feel like it :P, I don't know but it shouldn't make a differnce and yes the if statement is true

Comment: @David: I should bookmark that link :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var id = "original";
    var row = "some_row";
    var col = "some_col"
    var treasure_list = [];
    var grav_treasure_tree = function(id, row){
        // some code
    }

    var rand_id=Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
    var new_id = "treasure_grass_"+row+"_"+rand_id;
    new_id = new_id + "_col_" + col;
    treasure_list.push(new_id);
    if($("#"+id).length > 0){
        alert(new_id);
        $("#"+id).attr("id",new_id);
        grav_treasure_tree(id, row);
    }
});
```

That works if I have a div with id `original`:

```
<div id="original">
</div>
```

Comment: But I have a div with id of `id` it's displaying the alert so it must exist and so there shouldn't be a problem with  `$("#"+id).attr("id",new_id);`

Comment: So what error are you getting? What do your debugging tools showing you? And is the id literally id, as in `<div id="id">` or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: Okay, I have to apologise now, I've been sending you on a mission to find something that doesn't exist, I found what the problem is :) I put the wrong variable into a function :(, very stupid of me, but thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if($("#"+id).length > 0){
```

That checks to see if there is already an element on the page with the value of the "id" variable. I suspect that there is no such element at the time that code runs. That could be because

- the value of "id" is not what you think it is;
- the code runs at a point in time before the targeted element is part of the DOM

Comment: I think that perhaps you're not checking it properly. Of course, you have not posted the code that you think verifies that an element exists with an "id" value the same as the value of that variable, so it's not possible to say exactly what's wrong.